# Modify datetime.now() standard output

Tags: python, time

I what to change standard time output to "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00" format, how can I do it?
Here is what i have now.

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
print(start_date,"+00:00")
#output: 2019-04-19 06:57:47.563791 +00:00
#what to be: 2019-04-19T06:57:47.563791+00:00
```

Comment: `print(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"),"+00:00")` ?

Comment: Thanks, Rakesh, it works, gives "2019-04-19T07:19:09.466200 +00:00" , but is it any chance that I can remove this space  before "+"?

Comment: You can just use that string as an argument to `datetime.strftime`! Check my answer below on how to do that @干猕猴桃

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use exactly that format string with `datetime.strftime`:

```
datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to convert your datetime object to the required format

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
print(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00"))
#2019-04-26T12:50:45.219062+00:00
```